# ASP.NET MVC category model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When adding the category section, each category comes with one. But which element of the category do I want to attract, how can I do it.

I give examples from each category database. Category A has b c url. Category B also has URL b c. I have a table called `Menu`. If the category is true, I try to match it with the id in the `Menu` table from my `Category` table and display it.

Data model:

```
public static veri.Kategoriler[] deneme
{
    get
    {
        using (burakEntities db = new burakEntities())
        {
            return db.Kategorilers
                     .Include(p => p.Menuler)
                     .OrderByDescending(p => p.kategorilertarih)
                     .Where(p => p.KategoriAktif == "true"
                               & p.Menuler.KategoriMi == "true"
                               & p.Menuler.MenuMi == "false"
                               & p.Menuler.Menulerid == p.Menulerid)
                     .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`_category.cshtml` view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            @item.Menuler.MenuAdi
        </a>

        <!-- Dropdown menu -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@item.kategoriAdi</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
}
```

Output:

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to place your foreach inside the following code block. You are looping on a higher level; around the UL, thus you get more dropdowns instead of more dropdown-items.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          @foreach (var item in Model)
          {
             <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@item.kategoriAdi</a>
             </li>
          }
  </ul>
```

Comment: I give examples from each category database. Category A has b c url. Category B also has URL b c. I have a table called Menus. If the category is true, I try to match it with the id in the Menu table from my Category table and display it.

Answer (score -1):

problem solved

```
@foreach (var item in burak.Models.Data.kategorimi1)
{
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            @item.MenuAdi

        </a>
        <!-- Dropdown menu -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">

            @foreach (var i in burak.Models.Data.deneme)
            {
                if (item.Menulerid == i.Menulerid)
                {

                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@i.kategoriAdi</a>
                    </li>
                }

            }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**